# AngularJS newly push()'ed item to ngRepeat $Scope doesn't edit or delete effectively

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have been using Angularjs for a while now, and have encountered an odd problem.

Im rendering returned data into an `ng-repeat` i'm able to list the data ordered by the items _id thus showing the newest first. But when I created an add function that inserts a new item and uses `push` the subsequent item was added to the bottom of the list (when its needed to be at the top) This was no big deal as I just created an orderBy filter:

```
data-ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'_id':true"
```

This did the trick, when a new item is added bingo it is effectively prepended to the ng-repeat list. But (heres the tricky part) each item including the newly added item has the ability to be edited and deleted. This is done by the following:

```
// within ng-repeat
ng-click="deletePost($index,post._id)" 

// Subséquent function
$scope.deletePost = function(idx, id) {
    // Delete Post
    Blog.Post.delete({ id:id }, function(success) {
        $scope.posts.splice(idx, 1);
    })
}
```

The above does in-fact remove the item from the database, but within the ng-repeat list it removes the item below the desired item to be deleted. Has anyone experience this issue before? Or possible work arounds?

Could this be something to do with `track by` ?

Also a side note that if i completely remove the `orderBy` filter the delete and edit works effectively. But then i'm back where i started, and that being a newly added item appends to the bottom and not the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because `$scope.posts` has the items with original order when compared to ng-repeated item with orderBy. Orderby filter rearranges the item, returns a new array and repeats on it instead of the original `$scope.posts` array. So the index will be different if the original order is different from the sorted order.

And i believe you are just overdoing stuff, just pass the object as is and get its index for splicing from the original list.

just pass post from ng-click:

```
ng-click="deletePost(post)"
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.deletePost = function(post) { //Get post object
    var posts = $scope.posts;
    /*Delete with the _id property*/
    Blog.Post.delete({ id:post._id }, function(success) {
        /*Get the original index with the object reference and splice it*/
        posts.splice(posts.indexOf(post), 1);
    });
}
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.posts = [{
    _id: 'id1',
    name: 'Post1'
  }, {
    _id: 'id2',
    name: 'Post2'
  }, {
    _id: 'id3',
    name: 'Post3'
  }, {
    _id: 'id4',
    name: 'Post4'
  }]
  $scope.deletePost = function(post) {
    var posts = $scope.posts;
    posts.splice(posts.indexOf(post), 1);
  }
  $scope.addPost = function() {
    var posts = $scope.posts;
    posts.push({
      _id: 'id' + (posts.length + 1),
      name: 'Post' + (posts.length + 1)
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-click="addPost()">Add</button>
  <div data-ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'_id':true">
    <div ng-click="deletePost(post)">{{post.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove item by index maybe your $scope.posts order and rendered order not the same. When u use orderBy filter ng-repeat create new array for render, don't reorder $scope.posts.

You can remove item by its id. it is more safe.

```
var index;
$filter($scope.posts, function(val, key){
    if(val._id === id && !index)
        index = key;
})
if(index){
    $scope.posts.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Also if you want to show inserted row at first you should use unshift **instead** of **push**

Comment: Good call on the unshift Buddy :)